# OSX. Call didFinishLoadForFrame for WebView once?

Tags: macos, webview, load, frame

For example if I load website "intuit.ru" is called about 4 times. But it is enough for me first call only.

I tried to check if it is webView.mainFrame loaded and it allowed to execute the code inside this function once but the app works much slower with this way.

Comment: Because a page can have more than 1 frame.

Comment: but what to do if I need the first frame only?

Comment: Then you can try make a `BOOL` global variable or ivar, then set it to `YES` after the first frame.  Then set it back to `NO` when you load a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to check a varibale webView.isLoading inside this method